# How do I replace all occurrences of a string in HTML body by using request package in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, proxy, request

I just started a weekend project, my goal is to develop a tiny, primitive proxy server for bypassing the internet filtering.

Proxy server gets the desired URL from user within a parameter in URL query: `https://[PROXY_SERVER_URL]/?url=https://stackoverflow.com`

I'm using request package in a Node.js project for GETting the given URL and returning the page retrieved from given URL to the user:

```
 request({ url })
      .on("data", chunk => {
        data += replaceLinks(chunk, url)
      })
      .on("end", () => res.end(data))
      .on("error", e => res.end(e.toString()))
```

I would like replace all links on the page with this template `/url=https://[PROXY_SERVER_URL]/[WEBSITE_URL]/[LINK_URL]`

Inside the `replaceLinks` function, I am using String.replace:

`` const replaceLinks = (data, rootUrl) => data.toString().replace(/href="/, `href="/?url=${rootUrl}`) ``

However, I am getting only some links are replaced on the page. Many of them remain the same. Is there something that I'm missing with the asynchronous nature of Nodejs? Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Try making your regex global: /href="/g

Comment: It worked! thanks @Aurast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reqular expression must be global, like this:

```
/href="/g
```

Also, you might want to replace image URLs:

```
.replace(/src="/g, `src="/?url=${rootUrl}`);
```

Finally, remember to further improve your proxy to handle absolute URLs.